# Laravel 5.4 policy check always false

Tags: laravel, policy

So I have created a policy and registered it in the AuthServicePRovider, but it always returns false. It is my first time working with policies so I am sure I am doing it wrong, but following a few examples, nothing has worked for me.

AuthServiceProvider

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Article::class => ArticlePolicy::class,
    ];
```

ArticleController@show

```
public function show($article_id) I 
{
    $article = DB::table('pjt_article as a')
        ->join('pjt_categories_article as c', 'a.cate_id', '=', 'c.cate_id')
        ->where('article_id', $article_id)
        ->first();
    $this->authorize('view', $article->username);
    return view('admin.content.show-article', ['art' => $article]);
}
```

ArticlePolicy

```
public function view(Admin $admin, Article $article)
{
    return $admin->id == $article->username;
}
```

I'm try == and === but not working

This image error 403

[image]

Comment: Did you import the `Article` and  `ArticlePolicy` classes in the `AuthServiceProvider` ?

Comment: @Maraboc he did, look at the first code block

Comment: @Quezler i said import i mean `use App\Article` :p

Comment: In ArticlePolicy `use App\Model\Admin;
use App\Model\Article;`

Comment: If i'm not mistaken that would throw an exception before the page even renders :)

Comment: in AuthServicePovider `use App\Model\Article;`

Comment: yes and the also import ` ArticlePolicy` in the `AuthServicePovider` and `$this->authorize('view', $article);` !

Comment: I'm  do as you say, but it still error 403

Comment: Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176702/laravel-5-4-policy-check-always-false) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your policy is mapped to a Model classname. You would have to have a model instance to be able to do this. Your query is using Query Builder directly and not returning a Model instance.

```
$article = Article::....->first();
```

For `authorize` you want to pass the resource you want to authorize to `authorize` not the attribute on a resource you will eventually check in the policy:

```
$this->authorize('view', $article->username);

// to

$this->authorize('view', $article);
```

The way the Gate knows to even use a policy for a resource is because of the type of the object passed, or if passed a classname.

Comment: error at image`array:4 [ "ability" => "view" "result" => false "user" => 7 "arguments" => "[0 => Object(std`

Comment: I just understand what you post after. after @Maraboc help me And thank you both so much